# How to write a network packet in a dump file?

Tags: java, packet, coredump, packet-capture, jpcap

I am capturing packets using Jpcap and simply printing the captured packets which is working fine, but when i try to write the captured packets in dumpfile i get error message.

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>   EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000002c29eba,
>   pid=6892, tid=0x0000000000001afc  JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime
>   Environment (8.0_144-b01) (build 1.8.0_144-b01)  Java VM: Java
>   HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.144-b01 mixed mode windows-amd64
>   compressed oops)  Problematic frame:  v 
>   ~BufferBlob::jni_fast_GetLongField  Failed to write core dump.
>   Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows  An
>   error report file with more information is saved as: 
>   C:\Users\Asim\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication31\hs_err_pid6892.log
>   If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>   The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code. See 
>   problematic frame for where to report the bug.

```
JpcapWriter writer = JpcapWriter.openDumpFile(captor, "CapturedPackets");
                Packet packet = null;
                for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++){
                       packet = captor.getPacket();

                        if(packet!=null)
                        {
                           System.out.println(packet);
                           writer.writePacket(packet);         
                        }
                }
                writer.close();
```

`

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Does C:\Users\Asim\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication31\hs_err_pid6892.log not help? It sounds from the error message as if that may give you some guidance.

Comment: No the log file have the same error message which i have mentioned above.

Comment: OK, we'll have to wait for someone within the SO community who is expert in this area to pick this up.